# Scanning several lines of text from an external file in C

Tags: c, file, char, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose you have an external file named `test.txt` that contains the next block of text:

```
TEST1
TEST2
```

And you're supposed to:

1. scan the text
2. save it into a structue using DMA (dynamic memory allocation)
3. print out the result

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct test{
char *a;
char *b;

}VARIABLE;


int main(){

FILE *d1 = fopen("test.txt" , "r");

VARIABLE *x;

x = (VARIABLE *)malloc(sizeof(VARIABLE));

x->a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
fscanf(d1 , "%[^\n]s" , x->a);
printf("%s\n" , x->a);
free(x->a);

x->b = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
fscanf(d1 , "%[^\n]s" , x->b);
printf("%s\n" , x->b);
free(x->b);

free(x);

return 0;
}
```

of course, the expected output is an identical copy of `test.txt` but my output is only the first line of text from the external file (no matter how many lines of text i need to scan).
Output:

```
TEST1
```

What do i need to change/add/remove so my program works?

Comment: You read from the file twice with `fscanf` and you print to the console twice with `printf` and there is no loop ar anything else that suggests repetition. How many lines do you expect to be read? (Oh, and `sizeof(char)` is enough memory to hold a single char, which won't be enough. It also seems that you are supposed to read the whole contents of the file into your struct, then close the file, then print the contents and fnally clean up the struct. The way you do it right now - read, print, delete - doesn't need "DMA".)

Comment: you are only allocating enough for a 1-character string.  Your example is clearly longer than that.  Also your scanf stops at '\n'.  So does the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed / complete your code.

I used a local variable buffer to read lines from the file with `fgets()`. Then I remove ending `\n` that is read by `fgets()`, allocate memory for the length read and copy the string to the structure. Added a few sanity checks (could be more).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct test {
    char *a;
    char *b;
} VARIABLE;


int main() {
    FILE *d1;
    char bufa[100];
    char bufb[100];
    VARIABLE *x;

    d1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (d1 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found");
        return(1);
    }
    if (fgets(bufa, sizeof(bufa), d1) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read a");
        return(1);
    }
    bufa[strlen(bufa) - 1] = 0;  // Remove ending \n

    if (fgets(bufb, sizeof(bufb), d1) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read b");
        return(1);
    }
    bufb[strlen(bufb) - 1] = 0;  // Remove ending \n

    x = (VARIABLE *)malloc(sizeof(VARIABLE));

    x->a = (char *)malloc(strlen(bufa) + 1);
    strcpy(x->a, bufa);
    printf("%s\n", x->a);

    x->b = (char *)malloc(strlen(bufb) + 1);
    strcpy(x->b, bufb);
    printf("%s\n", x->b);

    free(x->a);
    free(x->b);
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: there are still room for improvements...

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted when it answer your question. Use the check mark on the left of the answer. This will help other user having the same issue.